# Sending files using slack-api

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, slack-desktop

curl -F file=@"/home/siva/Downloads/heap2.hprof.gz" -F channels="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxx" https://slack.com/api/files.upload

My file size is 150 mb
Iam not able send this file to slack
Using api

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have permissions to comment yet on here, but could you sanitize the output of `--verbose` on there so we can see the error message you are getting?  I'm also interested in seeing the `content-length` of the request header, Another theory I have after looking at the slack API that might work...

Try just not giving the "file" parameter, and do something like this:

`curl -v --trace /tmp/curl-upload.trace --data "channels="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&filename=somefile.gz&content=$(hexdump -x /home/siva/Downloads/heap2.hprof.gz| awk '{$1="";if($0) print $0}' | sed -re 's/([a-fA-F0-9]{2})([a-fA-F0-9]{2})/%\2%\1/g;s/\s//g' | tr -d '\n';)"  -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxx" https://slack.com/api/files.upload`

Might need to use --data-urlencode if you are going to manually pass the contents like that, either way I'd need to see more information about where in the process it is failing.